# How do I know when a ListBox has finished rendering in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, listbox, rendering

I need to know when a `ListBox` has finished rendering for the first time so that I can scroll it to the top to present the user with the first item on the list.

I have a `ListBox` that uses `RichTextBox` in it's `DataTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="HelpTextTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        ...
        <ContentControl>
            ...
            <RichTextBox x:Name="HelpTextContent" Grid.Row="1"
                         Tag="{Binding Path=HelpObject.Text, Mode=TwoWay}"
                         TextWrapping="Wrap"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                         Margin="0,0,20,0"
                         Loaded="RichTextBox_Loaded"
                         ContentChanged="RichTextBox_ContentChanged"
                         SelectionChanged="RichTextBox_SelectionChanged"/>
            ...
        </ContentControl>
        ...
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

The `ListBox` is bound to an `ObservableCollection`.

I had a problem with the scrolling of the `ListBox` - if height of the `RichTextBox` was greater than that of the `ListBox` the user couldn't scroll to the bottom of the `RichTextBox`. The `ListBox` would jump to the next item in the list. The height of the scroll bar's slider would change as well. This is because the actual height of the `RichTextBox` is only calculated when it's actually rendered. When it's off the screen the height reverts to smaller value (I think the code assumes that the text can all fit on a single line rather than having to be wrapped).

I tracked these problems down to the `ListBox`'s use of a `VirtualisingStackPanel` to draw the items. When I replaced that with a simple `StackPanel` those problems went away.

This then created the problem I have now which is that the `ListBox` scrolls to the bottom of the list on initial load. The `Loaded` and `LayoutUpdated` events on the `ListBox` occur before the data has been loaded. I tried listening out for the `PropertyChanged` event on the view model when the `ObservableCollection` is initialised:

```
void editViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.PropertyName)
    {
        case "ListDataSource":
            // Try to scroll to the top of the ListBox
            break;
    }
}
```

this fires too early as well. The list is rendered **after** this event is fired and causes the `ListBox` to scroll to the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I had to use a kludge:

```
private System.Threading.Timer timer;
void editViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.PropertyName)
    {
        case "ListDataSource":
            TimerCallback callback = TimerResult;
            timer = new Timer(callback, null, 750, 0);
            break;
    }
}

private void TimerResult(Object stateInfo)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        if (this.ItemsList.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            this.ItemsList.UpdateLayout();
            this.ItemsList.SelectedIndex = 0;
            this.ItemsList.ScrollIntoView(this.ItemsList.Items[0]);
        }
    });

    timer.Dispose();
}
```

If anyone knows a better way please post your answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to scroll in on Loaded handler, but delay it a bit by Dispatcher. Something like that

```
void OnLoaded(...)
{
   Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {/*Scroll your ListBox here*/});
}
```

It could help.

Comment: Hmm. I'm wary of things like this - especially as there could be a lot of items in the list - but I'll give it a go.

Comment: Since rendering takes place in UI thread, and Dispatcher.BeginInvoke pushes scrolling operation to the UI thread's queue - it actually does not matter how big your list is. Scrolling should be performed after other current UI-thread instructions are done. Of course if your collection (or other parts of control/template) is created async - it wont work. But it is another case.. Usually for simple scenarios it works.

Comment: I just tried this and no joy I'm afraid. The `Loaded` event is only called the once.

Comment: Of course if you assign ItemsSource with delay/async you cannot rely on Loaded event. I don't know details but if I understand your case correctly there is only one way to achieve your goal. You should notify UI when collection is ready and assigned. For example raise an event from ViewModel and subscribe your View to it and then try the trick I mentioned above. Anyway there is not such an event that could notify you that rendering is complete because of the way it is "rendered" - it's not static, it's alive.

Comment: Actually you can use LayoutUpdated when it is raised for the first time. Usually it means that control finished all its measures and arrangements and is ready ("rendered"). But if some parts of control's UI are changed (or for example control's parent container is updated etc) after the first measure/arrange trip - layout will be updated again. So you should use this approach carefully, taking into account your actual design. If you could provide me with some simple example that reproduces your case probably I could suggest you something more suitable.

Comment: Thanks for the update - I was really expecting it to fail - but I'm at the stage where I'll try anything :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AutoScrollBehavior : Behavior<ListBox>
    {
        #region Properties

        public object ItemToScroll
        {
            get { return GetValue(ItemToScrollProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemToScrollProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemToScrollProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemToScroll", typeof(object), typeof(AutoScrollBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(ItemToScrollPropertyChanged));

        private static void ItemToScrollPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ListBox lb = ((AutoScrollBehavior)d).AssociatedObject;
            lb.UpdateLayout();
            ((AutoScrollBehavior)d).AssociatedObject.ScrollIntoView(e.NewValue);
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

then use in the XAML as

```
<ListBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItemFromModel, Mode=TwoWay}">
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                                                <Behaviors:AutoScrollBehavior ItemToScroll="{Binding SelectedItemFromModel}"/>
                                                            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</ListBox>
```

on some command you should be able to control and set SelectedItemFromModel property of your view model.